# find the total differential of this equation $ xyz + \sqrt{ x^2 + y^2 + z^2} = \sqrt 2 $

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-differential-equations

How to calculate the total differential of $ z= z(x,y)$, which is  $ xyz + \sqrt{ x^2  + y^2 + z^2} = \sqrt 2 $ at point (1, 0, -1)？

The evaluation of mine seems wrong,

$ dz= \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}  dy = (yz+ \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2  + y^2 + z^2}})dx + (xz+ \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2  + y^2 + z^2}})dy  = \frac{dx}{\sqrt2} - dy $

Appreciate any helps.

Comment: $\frac{dz(x, y)}{(dy)} = \frac{(2 y-x^2 y-y^3-y z^2+2 x^2 y z^2+x^4 y z^2+2 x^2 y^3 z^2+x^2 y z^4-x^4 y^3 z^4)}{(z (-2+x^2+y^2-2 x^2 y^2-x^4 y^2-x^2 y^4+z^2-2 x^2 y^2 z^2+x^4 y^4 z^2))}$ according to wolfram.  Implicit differentiation is required I think but it seems nasty.

Comment: that's not dz, its d$f(x,y,z)$ it goes something like this

(i wont type square root, lot of typing )

$f(x,y,z(x,y))=xyz=\sqrt{2}$

$df=d(xyz)=0$

when you do partial derivative od f by x remember z if funcion of x

$  (yz + xy\frac{\partial z}{\partial x})dx + (xz + xy\frac{\partial z}{\partial y})dy+ xydz = 0  $ and now just solve to find  dz

$  dz=-\frac{(yz + xy\frac{\partial z}{\partial x})dx + (xz + xy\frac{\partial z}{\partial y})dy}{xy} $

i think its done this way, try it if you have solution see if it works

Answer (score 1):

I have done the following workings for the question.  I believe the answer is ok but please forgive if it is incorrect (and point out my oversight if possible).

As mentioned in the comments $z$ is implicitly a function of both $x$ and $y$.  To be specific $z=z(x,y)$

First let's calculate $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ remembering the product and chain rules:

You have:

$$xyz+\left( x^2+y^2+z^2 \right)^{1/2}=\sqrt{2}\\
yz+xy\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+\frac{1}{2}\left(2x+2z\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^{-1/2}=0$$

Now substitute $(1,0,-1)$ which, after simplifying, leads to $$2-2\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=0\implies\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=1$$

The case for$ \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$ plays out similarly: $$xz+xy\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}+\frac{1}{2} \left( 2y + 2z \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right) \left(x^2+y^2+z^2 \right)^{-1/2}=0$$

Now substitute $(1,0,-1)$ leading to $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=\sqrt{2}$

Now $dz=\frac {\partial z}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} dy \implies dz=dx+\sqrt{2}dy$